# What spell almost killed Hermione in The Order of the Phoenix?

Tags: harry-potter, spells

The spell was cast without words, simply a flick of the Death Eater's wand, and a 'streak of purple flame' that lanced across her chest. It was later mentioned that the spell was weakened because of the lack of a verbal component, but still 'did enough damage as it was'. She was in the infirmary healing from the damage for some time. What spell was this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The spell that Dolohov hit Hermione with was actually purple:

> But the Death Eater Hermione had just struck dumb made a sudden slashing movement with his wand; a streak of what looked like purple flame passed right across Hermione’s chest. She gave a tiny ‘Oh!’ as though of surprise and crumpled on to the floor, where she lay motionless.
>   <sub>*Order of the Phoenix* - page 698 - Bloomsbury - chapter 35, *Beyond the Veil*</sub>

I looked through the spells at the [Harry Potter Lexicon](http://www.hp-lexicon.org/) and the one spell that seemed possible is a [revulsion jinx](http://www.hp-lexicon.org/magic/spells/spells_r.html). The revulsion jinx repels and emits purple light when cast. This is the spell Hermione used on Yaxley in *Deathly Hallows* to shake him off the trio, when he had grabbed hold of Hermione as the trio attempted to Apparate from the Ministry of Magic to No twelve Grimmauld Place after they infiltrated the Ministry and retrieved the Slytherin locket from Umbridge (*Deathly Hallows*, chapter 13, *The Muggle-born Registration Commission*). A revulsion jinx could be considered an offensive spell, probably as well as a defensive one.

It's interesting that *Order of the Phoenix* indicates a non-verbal spell might be less effective than a verbal spell. Snape doesn't mention this when he teaches non-verbal spells in *Half-Blood Prince*.

Comment: I agree with your last comment, and no offense to JKR, but I strongly suspect she throws in non-verbal spells of varying strengths without any attempt at consistency, it seems to vary with the needs of the situation\scene in the book\movie.

Comment: She implies that verbal spells were really for the sake of the caster in order to properly prepare the spell in the minds of the casters, so logically seeing how non-verbal spells are more difficult, they're probably more likely to fail or be weaker by comparison.  Though, that's just speculation.

Comment: It wouldn't take much to break the concentration of someone casting a non-verbal spell.  Snape doesn't seem to indicate that they are necessarily more difficult, but I do seem to remember that he does say that one must concentrate in order to perform a non-verbal spell effectively.  And, let's be honest, some witches/wizards just probably aren't as proficient at casting non-verbal spells as others.

Comment: I think that somewhere inside of the books, it mentions that the curse is much more deadly when spoken. Might have been Madam Pomfrey or Dumbledore whilst in the hospital wing.

Comment: @slytherincess I'm sorry but this is nonsense. A Revulsion Jinx? The curse could have been fatal, not repulsive. It was a spell of Dark Magic, not a simple offensive jinx. See what Madam Pomfrey said about it. I know we have to speculate somethings but we must do so in reason. A Revulsion Jinx is not within reason. And why do you say "actually purple" as though to correct the asker? He specifically quoted that the spell produced a streak of purple flame.

Comment: @MermishEssence I appreciate your defense, but actually I had originally said something different and had edited my question after being corrected. Also while your opinion is duly noted, I tend to agree with Slytherincess for several reasons, the two most important is a lot of magic in a lot of worlds, Potter's included, can be multipurpose with the imagination and ingenuity of the caster being the only limitation, Also Slytherincess through her activity on this site shows one of the largest pools of Potter know-about I've ever seen.

Comment: That being said, a revulsion jinx could very easily be extremely damaging and fatal if changed to become a force push style effect, if I hit you in your chest hard enough your heart could burst and you could die.

Answer (score 2):

My best guess? A compression curse or crushing curse. Hermione's ribs were painful, it may be designed to inflict internal damage but fortunately it was diminished thanks to the silencing charm.

> "She winced slightly and put a hand to her ribs. The curse Dolohov had
>   used on her, though less effective than it would have been had he been
>   able to say the incantation aloud, had nevertheless caused, in Madam
>   Pomfrey's words, "quite enough damage to be going on with."

Still it must have been powerful enough to severely strike her and knock her out. It was further blunted by Harry's Shield Charm, yet it managed to knock him off his feet. Definitely a curse meant to strike very violently at the victim, perhaps violently enough to kill on the spot.

Answer (score -2):

It is a spell probably created by : 1) Voldemort , because in the "*Harry Potter & the Philosophers stone*" there was the Snapes task and there was a purple flame which you could cross after drinking the right potion and since Dolohov, Snape , Barty CrouchJR and the Lestranges were probably the most loyal followers he couls've taught it to them; 2)Antonin Dolohov bc he is a good spell creator so he could mix the *relashio* and *fiednfyre, incendio or confringo*

Comment: This seems like guesswork. Can you back it up with any evidence, as the other answers have done?